# Java Web Services without annotations in JDK1.4

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee

I have to develop a web service in java, But the constraint here is that I have to use JDK1.4, and the catch is that JDK1.4 doesn't support annotations.

Comment: Wow, using a technology made obsolete some 8 years ago? Talk about self-punishment! I suppose client is king... Then you have to do good old servlets, I suppose. No annotation, just support of GET / POST requests and reply back. Stuff like that.

Comment: @user1871707 - You should be able to use JAX-RPC if these are SOAP services.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Axis 2 or Axis 1 if former is impossible. It should be pretty easy as in old good days. :-)